Using the ninja build system how to specify a particular output in a rule?
I have a rule which generates two outputs, how to specify a particular output in the command for the rule.
In this case, I have a test rule, which uses the built executable to make a file.  I then
want to open the file as a preview.
I saw a reference to using $out1 to specify the second output, but that does not work on osx.
rule test3_r
    command = ./$in > $out1; open $out1
#    command = ./$exefile > out.gif
#    command = "./$exefile > out.gif; open out.gif"
    description = "tests by making gif and then display"

# test 3
build $
test3 $
out.gif $
: test3_r $exefile

And the output:
❯ ninja test3
[1/1] "tests by making gif and then display"
FAILED: test3 out.gif 
./lissajous > ; open 
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `./lissajous > ; open '
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


As a workaround this can be done but it does not answer the original question of how to specify a particular output in a build rule.  In this case, I am using the implicit output syntax.  However the implict output should really be out.gif and not the phony output, test3.  If do that,
then the out.gif is not in the $out.
Also note, the implicit=out.gif syntax in one reference seems to not be available now.
rule test3_r
    command = ./$in > $out; open $out
    description = "tests by making gif and then display"
#    implicit = out.gif

build $
out.gif $
| test3 $
: test3_r $exefile

And the result for specifying either output target will open the gif.
❯ ninja out.gif
[1/1] "tests by making gif and then display"

and
❯ ninja test3
[1/1] "tests by making gif and then display"

